# How can I take the number of index in my ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

I have the following code for a very simple ToDO list.

Here is my class to create a new task:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task {
    String tascDesc;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);   

    public Task() {}

    //Get the description from user
    public  String setTaskDesc() {
        System.out.println("Enter a task: ");
        tascDesc = scanner.nextLine();
        return tascDesc;
    }
```

A class to create a new list for the tasks:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class aList {
    //Create a new List
    ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
    Task task = new Task();

    //Add task to the List
    public void AddToList() {
        myList.add(task.setTaskDesc());
        System.out.println("New item " + task.tascDesc + " is added in your list!");
    }

    //Print the list with numbers
    public void PrintList(){
        for (int i = 0; i < myList.size(); i++) {
            int index = myList.indexOf(task.tascDesc);
            System.out.println(index + "." + task.tascDesc);
        }
    }
}
```

And the main/Testing Class for the program:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThingsUHave2Do {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        aList myList = new aList();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int toDo = 1;

        while (toDo != 3) {
            System.out.println("Enter 1 for create a task, 2 to print your list, 3 to exit.");
            toDo = scanner.nextInt();
            if (toDo == 1) {
                myList.AddToList();
            }
            if (toDo == 2) {
                System.out.println(myList.myList);
                myList.PrintList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Sorry if I had too many lines of code, but it's the only way I found to exactly explain my problem. So everything works as I want except that when I want to print the list, I want an output like:

1. buy sugar
2. learn java
3. Say thanks to everyone for the help.

I can't take the number of the index as the normal number. I made many tries but I don't have the desired result.

Comment: What does your output currently look like?

Comment: have you tried get() method?

Comment: @csmckelvey my output looks like  2.say thanks to everyone 2. say thanks to everyone 2.say thanks to everyone.I take the index only for the last task.

Comment: @AkshayRohilla Yes i tried it but with no result. i had almost the same output.

Comment: If i print my Arraylist, i have all tasks e.x [buy sugar] [ learn java ] [say thanks to everyone ]. So the loop should work and give me the index numbers of the tasks. It looks very simple but i cant figure out why is not working

Comment: That's because you keep looking up the same item over and over. `int index = myList.indexOf(task.tascDesc);` isn't changing during the loop.

Comment: You got like 2 different `Scanners` going here. In my opinion, you should not have a `Scanner` in your `Task` class.

Comment: @Sedrick You mean i have to ask user input for descriprion in main? I have one scanner for the task. The second is just for testing purpose to ask the user to enter a task, or print etc.

Comment: No, I said what I meant. In my opinion, that `Scanner` in your `Task` class is bad programming structure. Most `Java` classes consist of `Instance Variables`, `Constructors`, `Setters` and `Getters`.  Also, while I am in my opinion, I think the `List` should have been a `List<Task>`.

Comment: @Sedrick     As i m very new in java programming and general in OOP i respect and want your opinion. I will try what you suggest, even i m not sure that i really understand. As i want to make it as best i can for learning reason i ll follow your advice. Thank a lot!

Comment: @Sedrick Ifollowed your advice and you are right! TheTask class become better and gave me the way about adding the priority, the marked a task as complete in a moreright way. But for the second part, to make the List<Task>, even it was my first try i had problem to print the "description" of the task. Every time i had the Task ina type like Task@6e0be858 and because its a list of Tasks, i cant use the getter to print the description. Any idea in what way it can work?

Comment: It's probably something that's not to complicated. Start a new question.

Comment: try something like `List<Task> tasks = new ArrayList(); tasks.add(new Task(...)); for(Task task : task){System.out.println(tasks.getTaskDesc());}`

Comment: Actually is not complicated for you :) I m trying with toString(). I ll try everything i can and i ll start a new question.

Comment: @Sedrick    Everything works fine with .toString() overide in my Task class.This way even me i understand that my code is better and more ubderstanding. Really thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample app that demos your ideas.

> CustomTask Class

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication48;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class CustomTask
{

    String tascDesc;
    String priority;

    public CustomTask(String tascDesc, String priority)
    {
        this.tascDesc = tascDesc;
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public CustomTask(String tascDesc)
    {
        this.tascDesc = tascDesc;
        this.priority = "Low";
    }

    public void setTascDesc(String tascDesc)
    {
        this.tascDesc = tascDesc;
    }

    public String getTascDesc()
    {
        return this.tascDesc;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority)
    {
        this.priority = priority;
    }

    public String getPriority()
    {
        return priority;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return tascDesc + " : " + priority;
    }

}
```

> Main(Used to test CustomTask Class)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaApplication48
{

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<CustomTask> customTasks = new ArrayList();

        //One way to add to list
        CustomTask task1 = new CustomTask("first task!", "High");
        customTasks.add(task1);

        //Another way to add to list
        customTasks.add(new CustomTask("second task!")); //using this constructor automatically sets the priority to low

        //One way of printing list
        System.out.println("One way of printing list");
        for (int i = 0; i < customTasks.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Task " + i + ": " + customTasks.get(i).getTascDesc() + " - Priority: " + customTasks.get(i).getPriority());
        }

        //Another way to print list
        System.out.println("\nAnother way to print list");
        for (CustomTask task : customTasks) {
            System.out.println("Task : " + task.getTascDesc() + " - Priority: " + task.getTascDesc());
        }

        //Print using toString method
        System.out.println("\nPrint using toString method");
        for (CustomTask task : customTasks) {
            System.out.println(task);
        }

    }

}
```

> Output

```
run:
One way of printing list
Task 0: first task! - Priority: High
Task 1: second task! - Priority: Low

Another way to print list
Task : first task! - Priority: first task!
Task : second task! - Priority: second task!

Print using toString method
first task! : High
second task! : Low
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the efford. I ve done it that  way with your help already and have exactly the result i want. But i ll read your code carefully for learning!   https://github.com/Angelbreath/edx-portofolio1-sstilianidis

Answer (score -3):

Just change this line :

```
            System.out.println(index + 1 + "." + task.tascDesc);
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer but itsnot working. Actually the problem is that index is not giving me the index number of all tasks. Example: if user input is : buy milk, learn java, the output is 2.learn java 2.learn java

Answer (score -3):

```
            System.out.println(i + 1 + "." + myList.get(i));
```

Comment: Don't post 2 answers - just edit your first one. Also, you only need to indent code by 4 spaces.

Comment: @Parth Mody       Yeaaaaa this works. Thank you very much!!!  Now i have to understand what was wrong with my tries